# check if wordpress is updating or publishing a post

Tags: posts, updates

Very simple question: How can I check when wp is doing an update or a publishing to a post? Because I have to check a postmeta value which could be only true if the post is actually being published and so it has not to be already present in the system.
E.g. if( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) it's defined when wp is doing an autosave. Is there anything like this when it's doing an update?
Thank you!!

ok so

```
add_action('save_post', 'fields_news_save');
function fields_news_save($post_id){
$errors = false;
       if(get_check_key($_POST['checks_news'])==0){
    $errors = true;     
    update_option('custom_token', $errors);
    update_option('custom_admin_errors', $txt_err=error_text($errors, 2));

    remove_action('save_post','fields_news_save');
    wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'draft'));
    add_action('save_post', 'fields_news_save');

    return false;
}
}
```

The "if" clause check if there are meta post values set as $_POST['checks_news'] and this is the function which does the quer:
`function get_check_key($checker){
              global $wpdb;
              $data   =   array();
               $wpdb->query("
              SELECT *
              FROM $wpdb->wp_postmeta
              WHERE`meta_value`= $checker;
           ");
           return $wpdb->num_rows;
        }`

Now what i would like to do is the "if" at the beginnig checks if the number of rows is 0 AND wp is doing a publish not an update.

Comment: Could you post some code of where you are saving the postmeta. Do you mean you that only want to add the postmeta if the post is being published, and not add if it already is published..?

Comment: Hi Stephen, It's nothing about metadata, I only need to know in the backend (when I press the button publish/update) if it has been a publishing of a new post or an updating of an existing post.

Comment: @Tony, this is built in functionality. If a post has been published, the button will read "Update". If it hasn't been published, it will read "Publish".

Comment: Mind me asking why? If I know what you're trying to do, It'll be easier to help :D.

Comment: Is the save_post action something that would work for you? It's fired whenever wp_insert_post is called and works on auto drafts. It would definitely help to know what you're trying to do!

Comment: I haven't developed it yet, because i'm just wondering if i can perform this check when I press that button. In fact what i'm trying to achive is to understand, once i click the button and everything goes from the front to the back end, if the sistem is doing an "update" or a "publishing". To be much clearer: when you are in the post editing panel, wordpress knows if the post has or hasn't been published. But once i clik publish/update how can I know in my plugin if the post just sent was a new post or just an update of an existing one? I hope this clarify a bit

Comment: ...no, because i have already my plugin linked to this action. But what I need is in this plugin to know if the post is a new one or one that is already in the db.does wp define any vars somewhere which i can just check like if(define(UPDATE)){do something}?

Comment: @Tony Please edit your question to include your clarifying comments.  Including some psuedo code (not the real code you want to develop) to give us an idea of what information you're trying to grab and how you want to use it.

Comment: I put the code in the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I avoid the problem just checking if the ID of the post is already existing in the db.

```
get_post($id)==NULL
```

That's probably the easiest way to do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform an action when a "publish post", "save post", or "draft post" action is *taking place*, then simply add a callback to the appropriate **action hook**, i.e. `publish_post`, `save_post`, or `draft_post`.

If you need to perform an action *during the transition of a post from one status to another*, then you may want to use the appropriate [post status transition hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions).